# Form button 'Cannot set property 'onclick' of null'

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't determine what is 'null'.  I think it may be the form button, because of the form and button ids aren't the same...  The console is saying the problem is on the 'button1.onclick = createParagraph;' line.  Please help.

Below is my javascript

```
//global variables for user input
var noun1;
var noun2;
var adjective1;
var adjective2;
var verb1;
var verb2;
var paragraph1 = "hello, did this work?"
var button1 = document.getElementById("pushMe")

//to retrieve values from user input, and write to global variables
function handleSubmit(form) {
  noun1 = form.querySelector('input[name=noun1]').value;
  noun2 = form.querySelector('input[name=noun2]').value;
  adjective1 = form.querySelector('input[name=adjective1]').value;
  adjective2 = form.querySelector('input[name=adjective2]').value;
  verb1 = form.querySelector('input[name=verb1]').value;
  verb2 = form.querySelector('input[name=verb2]').value;

  return false;
}

//to write paragraph to the DOM
function createParagraph () {
  var element = document.createElement("p");
  var content = document.createTextNode("paragraph1");
  var location = document.getElementById("placeholder");
  element.appendChild(content);
  document.body.insertBefore(element,location);
}

//run it all!
button1.onclick = createParagraph;
```

Below is HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/madlib.css">
    <script src="randomMad.js"></script>
    <title>Mad Libs!</title>
  </head>
  <header>

  </header>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="return handleSubmit(this)" id="form1">
      <h1>Choose your words!</h1>
      <fieldset>
        <label>First Noun: <input type="text" name="noun1" ></label><br>
        <label>Second Noun: <input type="text" name="noun2"></label><br>
        <label>First Adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective1"></label><br>
        <label>Second Adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective2"></label><br>
        <label>First Verb: <input type="text" name="verb1"></label><br>
        <label>Second Verb: <input type="text" name="verb2"></label><br>
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" id="pushMe">Create Mad Lib</button>
    </form>
    <div id="placeholder">

    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: is randomMad.js where the above script is included?

Comment: Yes, that is the reference to the script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `;` in some of your lines..

See

```
var paragraph1 = "hello, did this work?"
var button1 = document.getElementById("pushMe")
```

Kindly add a `;` at the end of that two lines.

**UPDATE**

The error may be causing because you are trying to access the element before the DOM has finished loading. Thus to solve that problem, you can just move

```
<script src="randomMad.js"></script>
```

to the end of `<body>` .

Comment: I may be wrong here, but javascript can still run with semicolons omitted, so I don't think this is the issue. *Edit* Nevermind, it is required when using `"`, `'` or `()`.

Comment: Yes thats right.. @TimLewis .. Just to make sure that it is not the problem, he should try ending those lines with a `;`. I've updated my asnwer..